# Appending to struct slice in Go

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have two structs, like so:

```
// init a struct for a single item
type Cluster struct {
  Name string
  Path string
}

// init a grouping struct
type Clusters struct {
  Cluster []Cluster
}
```

What I want to do is append to new items to the clusters struct. So I wrote a method, like so:

```
func (c *Clusters) AddItem(item Cluster) []Cluster {
  c.Cluster = append(c.Cluster, item)
  return c.Cluster
}
```

The way my app works, I loop through some directories then append the name of the final directory and it's path. I have a function, that is called:

```
func getClusters(searchDir string) Clusters {

  fileList := make([]string, 0)
  //clusterName := make([]string, 0)
  //pathName := make([]string, 0)

  e := filepath.Walk(searchDir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    fileList = append(fileList, path)
    return err
  })

  if e != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error building cluster list: ", e)
  }

  for _, file := range fileList {

    splitFile := strings.Split(file, "/")
    // get the filename
    fileName := splitFile[len(splitFile)-1]

    if fileName == "cluster.jsonnet" {
      entry := Cluster{Name: splitFile[len(splitFile)-2], Path: strings.Join(splitFile[:len(splitFile)-1], "/")}
      c.AddItem(entry)

    }
  }
  Cluster := []Cluster{}
  c := Clusters{Cluster}

  return c

}
```

The problem here is that I don't know the correct way to do this.

Currently, I'm getting:

> cmd/directories.go:41:4: undefined: c

So I tried moving this:

```
Cluster := []Cluster{}
c := Clusters{Cluster}
```

Above the for loop - `range`. The error I get is:

> cmd/directories.go:43:20: Cluster is not a type

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the loop where you are calling `AddItem` function on Cluster method receiver which is not defined inside `getClusters` function. Define `Cluster` struct before for loop and then call the function `c.AddItem` as defined below:

```
func getClusters(searchDir string) Clusters {

    fileList := make([]string, 0)
    fileList = append(fileList, "f1", "f2", "f3")

    ClusterData := []Cluster{}
    c := Clusters{Cluster: ClusterData} // change the struct name passed to Clusters struct

    for _, file := range fileList {

        entry := Cluster{Name: "name" + file, Path: "path" + file}
        c.AddItem(entry)
    }
    return c

}
```

you have defined the same struct name to `Clusters` struct that's  why the error

> cmd/directories.go:43:20: Cluster is not a type

Checkout working code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VzDEDq_qysh)

In Golang [Composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) is defined as:

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They
>   consist of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of
>   elements. Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding
>   key.

Also Have a look on struct literals section defined in above link for `Composite`literals to get more description.

Comment: As soon as I read your answer, I could see what I'd done! Thanks, the key was changing the struct name. Perhaps I need more coffee, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `c` **before** entering the loop in which you use it.

The `Cluster is not a type` error is due to using the same `Cluster` name as the type and the variable, try using a different variable name.

```
clusterArr := []Cluster{}
c := Clusters{clusterArr}

for _, file := range fileList {
   ....
}
```